# Number guessing game in JS

Tags: javascript, html, random

I want to create a number game where the user enters a number from 1-100, and it the script will attempt to guess in 10 guesses the user's input. If within 10 guesses it guesses the right number it wins, otherwise the user wins. So far I got it work properly, except I'm having issues trying to have it display the number of guesses made at the end of the game. So for example, if 10 guesses were made than it should show "Number of guesses made: 10" or Number of guesses made: 5" (if guessed in 5).

```js
window.guessNum = function () {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
    var guesses = 10;
    var input = parseInt(document.getElementById("numberGuess").value);
    do {
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
         
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "I'll guess " + randomNum + " <br />";
        if (input == randomNum) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Our numbers match. I win!! :)<br /><br />";
        guesses = 0;
       }
       if (input < randomNum) {
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Your input is less than the number I'm thinking about. <br /><br />";
       } else if (input > randomNum) {
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Your input is greater than the number I'm thinking about.<br /><br />";
       }
       guesses = guesses - 1;
       }
       while (guesses > 0);
       if (input != randomNum) {
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "I can't figure it out. I guess you win!<br /><br />";
       }
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Number of guesses: " +guesses+ " <br />";
    }
```

```html
<h1>Number Game</h1>
<div id="mainCont">
  <p>Number:
    <input type="text" id="numberGuess">
    <input type="button" onclick="guessNum();" value="Guess">
  </p>
  <div id="guess"></div>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the question? Is there something wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: yes the output is not doing as wanted. It displays the script's guess 10 times, and than shows the comparison 10 times either showing if it was less than or greater than the user's input. After that it goes straight to I can't figure out you're number. I want it to be able to guess within 10 times different numbers and compare the user's input. Also the display of the results is not right. It should show what the script is guessing than show whether or not it's greater than or less than the number. Afterwards, it should guess another number. until 10 guesses have made or not.

Comment: You generate randomNum once, before you call the function, and you compare the inputted number to the same thing [over and over again](https://xkcd.com/221/).  At least the line that generates randomNum should be inside the function, better however to figure out how to guess it in 10 guesses.

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/j0bbnhue/3 , i did some changes on your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate a new random number in every loop (not just at the beginning)

Comment: I put it after the do before the innerHTML I'll guess a number. I lowered the range from 1-10 in 5 chances and now it's guessing 7 times, and even when I got the right number it doesn't close out saying It wins.

Answer (score 0):

The first one i noticed was the below line was out of the loop

```
 var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
```

and then the below line was not there if the numbers were equal, so it went to recurring loop.

```
guesses = guesses - 1;
```

and for show the guess and its result one after another it , i appended all the result to single `div`

**see the below working demo:**

```js
window.guessNum = function () {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
    var guesses = 10;
    var input = parseInt(document.getElementById("numberGuess").value);
    do {
        //guesses--;
          var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<p>I 'll guess " + randomNum + " </p>";

        if (input < randomNum) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<p>Your input is less than the number I'm thinking about. </p>";
        } else if (input > randomNum) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<p>Your input is greater than the number I'm thinking about.</p> ";
        }
         guesses = guesses - 1;
    }
    while (guesses > 0);
    if (input != randomNum) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<p>I can 't figure it out. I guess you win!</p>";
    }
    if (input == randomNum) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<p>Our numbers match. I win!! :)</p>";
        guesses = 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Number Game</h1>

<div id="mainCont">
    <p>Number:
        <input type="text" id="numberGuess">
        <input type="button" onclick="guessNum();" value="Guess">
    </p>
    <div id="guess"></div>
    <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/j0bbnhue/4/

Comment: Were you able to see if it ever hit the time where if it guessed the users input it says he user win. I've been trying and so far no luck. Especially in 10 or fewer guesses

Comment: Yes i was able to get it, but for testing purpose i just hardcoded the variable `randomNum` to get this `Our numbers match. I win!! :)` output.

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance. I really appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

to generate a number you have to execute this line of code

```
var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
```

then we create a function to do that and returns the random number

```
function getRandomNumber()
{
   var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
   return randomNum;
}
```

then we would create a variable to store the random number from the function

```
var number = getRandomNumber();
```

after that it's very simple we create a function to check if the guess is the same as the variable number

```
function CheckNumber(guessNumber)
{
   //checks if guessed number is the random number we stored
   if(guessNumber === number)
   {
    //success we alert saying you win
    alert("You Win!");
   }
   else
   {
    //not the same number
    alert("Wrong!,Try again")
   }
}
```

full code

```
 function getRandomNumber()
    {
       var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
       return randomNum;
    } 
var number = getRandomNumber();
function CheckNumber(guessNumber)
    {
       //checks if guessed number is the random number we stored
       if(guessNumber === number)
       {
        //success we alert saying you win
        alert("You Win!");
       }
       else
       {
        //not the same number
        alert("Wrong!,Try again")
       }
    }
```